# Как обновить mounted событие?

Tags: vue.js, api

Есть новостная лента, сообщения подгружаются по api (через axios) и подвешено все на mounted. **Нужно сделать кнопку по клику на которую будет происходить обновление всех сообщений.** То есть, чтобы шел новый запрос и происходила отрисовка. Как это можно сделать? Спасибо!
Сейчас происходит все примерно так:

```
mounted() {
  axios
    .get('https://site.ru/api/message.php', {})
    .then(response => { ... })
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помещаешь в метод. Метод вызываешь в `mounted`. Метод вызываешь по кнопке.

Comment: Точно, спасибо))